# AWS MemoryDB not connecting after recreating it

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, stackexchange.redis, amazon-memory-db

I have installed aws memory db via terraform. and connected it with .net like the way below.

```
services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(option =>
           {
               option.ConfigurationOptions = new ConfigurationOptions()
               {
                   EndPoints =
                   {
                       { redisConfig.Endpoint, redisConfig.Port } // Cluster endpoint
                   },
                   User = redisConfig.User,
                   Password = redisConfig.Pass,
                   Ssl = redisConfig.SSL,
                   AbortOnConnectFail = redisConfig.AbortConnect,
                   ConnectTimeout = 60000
               };
               //option.Configuration = $"{redisConfig.Host}:{redisConfig.Port},password={redisConfig.Pass},ssl={redisConfig.SSL},abortConnect={redisConfig.AbortConnect}";
           });
```

but after deleting and recreating it my memorydb suddenly stopped connecting it and throw a connection error. Error is down below

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: No connection is active/available to service this operation: HMGET emv-test@gmail.com; UnableToConnect on clustercfg.xxxxx.xxxxx.memorydb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:6379/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 0s ago, last-write: 0s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 0s ago, v: 2.2.50.36290, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: DESKTOP-V0GJHRO, IOCP: (Busy=2,Free=998,Min=8,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=5,Free=32762,Min=8,Max=32767), v: 2.2.50.36290
 ---> StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: UnableToConnect on clustercfg.newredis.78ank7.memorydb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:6379/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 0s ago, last-write: 0s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 0s ago, v: 2.2.50.36290
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ThrowFailed[T](TaskCompletionSource`1 source, Exception unthrownException) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 2799
```

It was working but all of a sudden it stopped working. I need help

Comment: Deleting and recreating it didn't change the endpoint?

Comment: yes because its name is same but i ve tried with different settings too nothing is working atm